# Boost - cannot get exception information

Tags: exception, boost

I had found the solution to this but I removed the code and today, I just cannot build this

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (boost::exception const& ex)
{
    std::cerr << *boost::get_error_info<errmsg_info>(ex) << std::endl;
}
```

gives me

```
error: no template named 'get_error_info' in namespace 'boost'; did you mean 'error_info'?
```

I tried

```
std::cerr << boost::diagnostic_information(ex) << std::endl;
error: no member named 'diagnostic_information' in namespace 'boost'


std::cerr << boost::get_error_info(ex) << std::endl;
error: no member named 'get_error_info' in namespace 'boost'
```

same sort of errors, diagnostic_information unknown, get_error_info unknown

Please help me out on this

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to include

```
#include <boost/exception/get_error_info.hpp>
```